# Component link hover style to use hover

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-router-dom

I use the react-router-dom to create my routes because this has use component Link in my menu, but I want to custom that component. I have customing with const and Work, but my hover does't work.

My code:

```
<Link className="ui-link" style={styles.menuStyle} to={'/home'}> 
     <MdStore size={25} color="#5f5f5f" />
     <Opt>Consumidores</Opt> 
</Link>
```

My CSS, but my hover does't work:

```
const styles = {
    menuStyle: {
        textDecoration: 'none',
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: '10px',
        borderRadius: '8px',
        margin: '5px 0px',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#171717',
        },
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do not use the className="ui-link" and create a style to class?

For example:

```
a.ui-link:hover {
   backgroundColor: '#171717';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if you can do it like that, You can do one of the following:

1. Use styled components there you can simply style your Link tag with
   whichever styles you want with pure css code
2. Use mouseEnter, mouseLeave events
3. Style it the regular way you would